# Login on website via PowerShell Invoke-Webrequest with form action URL

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, automation

I'm trying to login on a website using Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell.
I've seen how it's usually done by POSTing the required field inputs in the login form.

The website i'm using however has a completely new URL as 'Action' for the form, with a new session code.

This is what I've been trying:

```
$URL = 'https://account.engie.be/'
$username = "email"
$password = "pw"

$Site = Invoke-WebRequest $URL -SessionVariable Session1

$Form = $Site.Forms
$ActionURL = $Form.Action

$Form.Fields['username'] = $username
$Form.Fields['password'] = $password
$Form.Fields['rememberMe'] = "off"

$Site2 = Invoke-WebRequest $ActionURL -WebSession $Session1 -Method Post -Body $Form.Fields
```

$Site2 turns out to be exactly the same as $Site, with all empty fields and without actually logging in.

Any suggestions on how to pass the username and password to login and proceed to the next page?

Comment: ***Some sites block some if not all automation efforts on their sites. If that is the case, there is little that can be done.*** You need to first scrape the site for details, don't guess at it. Use your browser dev tools to mine for details. If it is multi-page, then it's even more problematic. If objects are dynamically generated based on previous actions, then more issues.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, all that is needed to login into a site is stuff like this:

```
# Discovery
$w = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://account.engie.be/' -SessionVariable WebSession

$w.Forms | 
FOrmat-List -Force
# Results
<#
Id     : login-form
Method : post
Action : https://account.engie.be/auth/realms/BE_MS_Customers/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=FvHizN61Ma-M6ihNIy1gR9_He1laU5GjEYFbh5Pvs1I&execution=2de78925-6c25-4a2a-a77e-1684
         0d0f908e&client_id=magnolia&tab_id=Xa8oyXE8RsI
Fields : {[username, ], [password, ], [rememberMe, on]}
#>

$w.Forms[0].Fields
# Results
<#
Key        Value
---        -----
username        
password        
rememberMe on   
#>

$w.AllElements

# Actions
$username = "email"
$password = "pw"

$form = $w.Forms[0]
$form.fields['username'] = $username
$form.fields['password'] = $password
$form.Fields['rememberMe'] = 'off'

($w = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ('https://account.engie.be/' + $form.Action) -WebSession $WebSession -Method POST -Body $form.Fields)
# Results
<#
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html class="">
                    
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8">
                        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
                        <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compat...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
                    X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.google.com
                    Referrer-Policy: same-origin, strict-origin-wh...
Forms             : {login-form}
Headers           : {[Transfer-Encoding, chunked], [Connection, keep-alive], [X-XSS-Protection, 1; mode=block], [X-Frame-Options, ALLOW-FROM https://www.google.com], [Referrer-Policy, 
                    same-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin], [Content-Security-Policy, frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.bnl-ms.myengie.com https://*.engie.be;...
....
#>
```

With the exception of from index, it's the same as what you have. However, directly going to the site in my sandbox and in a private session, other dialogs are presented that need to be responded to.

So, as per my comment, this site construct is set to limit, inhibit and or restrict automation as far as I can tell from it.